PowerBI slicer with overlapping categories
I've got a table which contains rows belonging to three overlapping categories.
I want to filter the table dynamically using a slicer.
To be exact: I have row numbers and want the end user to be able to toggle between showing rows 1-13, rows 1-26, and rows 1-65. I want to give each of these ranges friendly names and for the user to be able to toggle between the categories using a single select slicer. I'd like to avoid using a sliding bar because it is deeply unintuitive in the context.
Is there a way to do this in PowerBI? It seems like it should be easy but I've struggled to get any traction on the problem.

One option, which I'm not completely happy with, is to deconflict the categories within the data source. This can be done in the M-Code layer or in a SQL view prior to reaching PowerBI.
The rows which match multiple categories can be duplicated such that the categories no longer overlap. The categories can then be denoted using a new field. In my specific case this would mean:
Rows 1-13 -> Three copies of each row, one with category "A", one with category "B", one with category "C"
Rows 14-26 -> Two copies of each row, one with category "B", one with category "C"
Rows 27-65 -> One copy of each row, with category "C"

Disadvantages to the approach:

It means duplicating quite a lot of data
The dataset becomes more complicated than it should be, making it more likely someone will make a mistake in the future


If you are able to post some data and provide more clarity on what the expected result is someone may be able to help.
